# What does InputMismatchException Mean?

Tags: java, exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

What it indicates for me while I'm using it with scanner class? Complete stacktrace is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at ParseString.main(ParseString.java:9)
```

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace

Comment: @ss234 - In English, 1 question mark is enough.  We also use capital letters, and real words ... not lazy abbreviations like 'plz'.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the docs at the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html).

The answer should be clear:

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

Comment: +1 - if the OP needs a more specific answer, he/she needs to post the code AND the input it was trying to read when the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html):

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

So maybe you've called `nextInt` but the next token is "1.5" or "foo". You should look at the stack trace to see exactly which `Scanner` call caused the problem, and then work out what the token actually was, and how you want to handle that sort of failure.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the according javadoc (for example: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html ). The Exception is raised if the input does not match the method you used to get it, for example you use getBoolen but the next value can not be translated into a boolean.